# ANOVAs from SPSS and R report different degrees of freedom. Which are correct?

Tags: r, anova, spss, degrees-of-freedom

I am conducting a reanalysis of some data. The dv is continuous (beta value ie neural activity) and the iv is categorical (position) with three levels (1, 2, 3). There are 126 observations. The original analysis was conducted in SPSS and the original paper reports F(2,82) = 43.058, p = 0.00.  I am conducting my analysis in R, and I am getting residuals df of 123. Here is the table:

```
> summary(aov(Beta ~ Position, data = cFFA_same))
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
factor(Position)   2  118.3   59.13    4.08 0.0193 *
Residuals        123 1782.7   14.49                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I am quite poor in statistics - can anyone explain which df are correct and why/how they affect the F statistic and p value in this way?

Edit: The design is repeated measures, and I have seen that I should be using `aov_car` from the afex package instead of Anova/aov. However, I get the same output for both:

```
Anova(lm(Beta ~ Position, data = cFFA_half))

Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: Beta
           Sum Sq  Df F value Pr(>F)
Position    50.73   2  1.4999 0.2272
Residuals 2080.08 123
```

```
aov_car(Beta ~ Position + Error(Beta), data = cFFA_half)

Contrasts set to contr.sum for the following variables: Position
Anova Table (Type 3 tests)

Response: Beta
    Effect     df   MSE    F  ges p.value
1 Position 2, 123 16.91 1.50 .024    .227
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘+’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I was also not sure what to use as the error term. Is this the problem?

Comment: summary(aov(Beta ~ as.factor(Position), data = cFFA_same)) should give the same freedom. Position is a categorical iv, this needs to be reflected in formula.

Comment: @xiaoA position is already treated as a factor without making it explicit in the formula. You can see this in the number of degrees of freedom associated with the variable, which is 2 (as expected for a factor variable with 3 levels) and not 1 (as expected for numerical variable).

Comment: Part of the code to make the dataframe included making position a factor: `cFFA_same$Position<−factor(cFFAsame$Position, levels = c("1", "2", "3"))`

Answer (score 2):

You have different degrees of freedom for the residuals 123 vs 82.

This indicates that you probably are

- working with different data (the original paper does not have 126 observations)

or

- you are doing several steps differently (e.g. the original paper might have used some selection of the data or has additional variables in the model).

It is not possible to see what it is exactly. In order to answer more specifically about this you should make your question more detailed. Ideally the question should be made reproducible (e.g. provide links to the data and original research).

Comment: It is definitely the same data and in its entirety. The design is repeated measures, which apparently the `Anova` function I used isn't set up for. I have tried with `aov_car` from afex which is apparently specifically for this kind of design, but I am getting the same output

Comment: @danielb a repeated measures design falls into the category 'or you are doing several steps differently' and more specifically 'additional variables in the model'. But to answer with more detail you should provide more details about the data and the analysis. 
Make your question reproducible. I can not see how your data is definitely the same as the data from the original research.

Comment: In addition, it is unclear how the repeated design works for your case. It seems like you do not have a fully repeated measures design, because in that case I would expect the difference in degrees of freedom to be a multiple of two or three.